# Show that the tetragonal crystal is a tensor of an electrical conductivity which is isotropic in the plane which is orthogonal to the tetragonal axis

Tags: electrostatics, atomic-physics, symmetry

> **My problem**: Show that the tetragonal crystal is a tensor of an electrical conductivity which is isotropic in the plane which is orthogonal to the tetragonal axis.

- I might use Ohm's law in the tensor notation.
- The magnitude of the current is independent against the direction of the voltage.
- The tensor of the electrical conductivity looks like:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} &\sigma_{13} \\
        \sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22} & \sigma_{23} \\
        \sigma_{31} & \sigma_{32} & \sigma_{33} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

- For Ohm's law $J = \sigma E$ $\;$we have:

$$
       J = \begin{pmatrix}
        \sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} &\sigma_{13} \\
        \sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22} & \sigma_{23} \\
        \sigma_{31} & \sigma_{32} & \sigma_{33} \\
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \ E_1  \\
        \ E_2  \\
        \ E_3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $J$ is the current density, $E$ is the electrical intensity and $\sigma$ is the electrical conductivity.

- I think I might look at the elements of the symmetry in my given crystal...
- I don't know actually what I should do, I don't have a good sense of the spatial orientation and sorry for my English. My brain hurts from this example, please help me.

Comment: perhaps you could start by discussing what you have done?

Comment: I have already found the solution.

Comment: I’d be incredibly grateful if you were willing to share the answer to this problem that you found. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I haven't been there for ages. Do you still want to see the solution? @Lucienrien